# Proving from (a/b + b/c + c/a) being natural that abc is some natural number cubed

Tags: linear-algebra

$a, b, c \in \Bbb Z$

$a, b, c, \gt 0$

$(\frac {a}{b} + \frac {b}{c} +\frac {c}{a})  \in \Bbb Z$
How to prove that
$abc$ is an integer cubed?

Comment: First step: Reduce to the case where $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just like nonzero integers have a decomposition into prime powers and a  $\pm 1$ unit factor so do the nonzero rational numbers, except that the exponents can be negative.

For $p$ a prime number define 
$$v_p\colon \mathbb{Q}^{\times} \to \mathbb{Z}$$
$v_p(r) = $ exponent of $p$ in the prime decomposition of $r$. It is easy to see that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
v_p(r_1 \cdot r_2) = v_p(r_1) \cdot v_p(r_2)\\
\end{eqnarray*}
and 
$$r = \mathrm{sign\ }r \cdot \prod_p p^{v_p(r)}$$
for all $r\ne 0$ rational.

Denote by $r_p$ the factor $p^{v_p(r)}$ ( the $p$-part of r). We'll use this later.

A moment thought convinces us that we also have 
$$v_p( \sum_i r_i) \ge \min ( v_p(r_i) )_i$$
(think of the denominators -- more or less).
Moreover, a very important particular case is : if the minimum $\min (v_p(r_i)$ is achieved at exactly one index $i_0$ then in the above inequality we have $\it{equality}$.
Think of adding several integers and a half integer ($v_2(r_{i_0})= -1$), you  get a half integer.

Another important observation : if $v_p(r) < 0$ then $r$ is not an integer.

We have all the tools now. Take any prime $p$. We have $a/b \cdot b/c \cdot c/a = 1$ and so $v_p(a/b) + v_p(b/c) + v_p(c/a) = 0$. Consider the minimum of $v_p(a/b)$, $v_p(b/c)$,
$v_p(c/a)$. It is $\le 0$. If the minimum is $<0$ it has to be achieved  more than once
because $a/b$, $b/c$ and $c/a$ sum up to an integer. It the minimum is $0$ then all of the values are $0$. In either case, two of the values $v_p(a/b)$, $v_p(b/c)$, $v_p(c/a)$ are equal. Say $v_p(a/b)= v_p(b/c)$. That means $b_p$ is the geometric mean of $a_p$ and $c_p$ and therefore $a_p \cdot b_p \cdot c_p = b_p^3$ is a cube. 
We can do this for any prime divisor of some of the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$. Therefore

$$abc = \pm 1 \prod_p (abc)_p = \pm 1 \prod (a_p \cdot  b_p \cdot c_p)$$
a product of cubes so a cube itself.